# update neovim from official repos

Tags: repository

I'm using fedora 25 and I've installed neovim, when it was really new via some copr called dperson/neovim.
I now saw [this](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/?packages=neovim) which seems to me as if the standard sources for fedora have neovim included by now.
So now if I type sudo dnf install neovim- 
I still only get versions up to 0.1.7.4, but there is 0.2 on the official server?!

How do I manage to see, what should be there imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The bodhi page for this package update](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2017-c1f29e2fbb) mentions that it has been moved from testing to stable just 2 hours ago, but this change has not been pushed to the repositories yet. Fedora only updates its repositories once a day, so you need to wait a bit more.

Alternatively you could just install it from the updates-testing repository:

```
sudo dnf install --enablerepo=updates-testing neovim
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much. I thought I cannot reach the repo or something. Also of course I did not notice the timestamp, since 0.2.* was there in source code for a bit now. And also I was expecting in-betweens..